# Unity Beginner - 2d game: detect position of tap on quad

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I have a huge Quad and a PNG as a child object.

The PNG covers the whole game area / screen.

I know how to detect taps, but how can I detect when a user tapped on the left side of the PNG/quad vs. the right?

Should I place 2 gameobjects above the big quad to capture inputs on right or left? Or maybe I could capture the tap on the main big quad but I do a calculation to find out where it as tapped, like this:

```
if (tappedPosiion > quadWidth / 2)
{
    // it's the right side
} else {
    // its the left
}
```

The problem is I don't know how do I find out the width of the current game object!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renderer.bounds.size should work (or collider.bounds.size)

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/24012/find-size-of-gameobject.html

You can then access the width by getting the x value:

"size.x is the width, size.y is the height and size.z is the depth of the box."

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds-size.html

Now you have the width, so it should be relatively easy to find out where they tapped.

```
if(tappedLocation == width/2)
//middle

if(tappedLocation > width/2)
//right side

if(tappedLocation < width/2)
//left
```

pretty basic but answers your question on how to find width and see where they tapped based on that information.